# Ubuntu Server cron job doesn't work

Tags: server, cron

My script that is supposed to run only when the server is on isn't working correctly when run by cron. If I run it manually, it works.

```
backup() {
  if pidof java &> /dev/null; then

     screen -p 0 -S minecraft -X eval "stuff \"say server backing up\"\015"
     # We need to first put the server in readonly mode to reduce the chance of backing up half of a chunk.
     screen -p 0 -S minecraft -X eval "stuff \"save-off\"\015"
     screen -p 0 -S minecraft -X eval "stuff \"save-all\"\015"

     sleep 10


     cd ~/Minecraft
     mkdir backup
     tar cvfpz backup/Y-$(date +%Y_M-%m_D-%d_T-%H_%M)-world.backup.tar.gz world/

     screen -p 0 -S minecraft -X eval "stuff \"save-on\"\015"
     screen -p 0 -S minecraft -X eval "stuff \"say server done backing up\"\015"

     # Delete old backups
     echo deleting old backups
     find . -name '*-world.backup*' -mtime +5 -delete

   else
      echo Minecraft Server not on
   fi
 }
```

I'm wondering if anyone knows why it's not stopping the backup if the server is stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the crontab file look like that is supposed to start that script?
And what are the permissions/owner of the script?

On [this link](http://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html) I found:

1. When cron job is run from the users crontab it is executed as that user. It does not however source any files in the user's home directory like their .cshrc or .bashrc or any other file. If you need cron to source (read) any file that your script will need you should do it from the script cron is calling. Setting paths, sourcing files, setting environment variables, etc.
2. If the users account has a crontab but no usable shell in /etc/passwd then the cronjob will not run. You will have to give the account a shell for the crontab to run.
3. If your cronjobs are not running check if the cron deamon is running. Then remember to check /etc/cron.allow and /etc/cron.deny files. If they exist then the user you want to be able to run jobs must be in /etc/cron.allow. You also might want to check if the /etc/security/access.conf file exists. You might need to add your user in there.
4. Crontab is not parsed for environmental substitutions. You can not use things like $PATH, $HOME, or ~/sbin. You can set things like MAILTO= or PATH= and other environment variables the /bin/sh shell uses.

So, I'd start by editing the cronjob itself and changing the ~ to /home/popcorn9499.
Then do the same for the script.
Also in the script add `#! /bin/bash` as the first line.

If everything in the script is just the function `backup() {` take that line out and the final `}` and make it a plain bash script. You can then loose the `backup` argument and teh cronjob becomes: `*/30 * * * * /home/popcorn9499/Scripts/minecraft.sh`
(you really need to make a backup every 30 minutes?)

Next, make sure you have rwx permission for the scriptfile: `chmod u+rwx ~/Scripts/minecraft.sh`

Finally, consider renaming your directory `~/Scripts` to `~/bin` as that is already in your $PATH.

That should fix things.

Comment: the permissions are all set up to everyone i think and everything is set correctly as far as i know cause its working just not stopping it if java not on

Comment: When you run a script manually you may be running it with different permissions than when cron executes it. Is it started from `/etc/crontab` or `crontab -e`? Where is the script stored and what are the exact permissions, what does the cronjob definition look like?

Comment: it is stored in my /home/popcorn9499/Scripts/ and whats the cron job definition unless it looks like this */30 * * * * ~/Scripts/minecraft.sh backup and it started from crontab -e

Comment: @popcorn9499: Try expanding the tilde (~) to /home/popcorn9499.

Comment: @popcorn9499 : Love to know if you got it working as described above.

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond got busy and was stupid. but i did get this working been using the script to this day. Modified it abit but its working great thanks